# iPhone - Image created with CGBitmapContextCreate as Opengl texture

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, cgbitmapcontext

I want to call `CGBitmapContextCreate` with texture->data to create a `CGContextRef`,
and create a `CGImageRef` by `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`(context).

However, the image created is not as expected :(

The one created from `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`:

[image]

The actual one (slight different since I take it with another camera):

[image]

Codes: (`texture.bytesPerPixel = 2`)

```
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(texture.data, 512, 512, 5, 512 * texture.bytesPerPixel, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    CGImageRef cg_img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* ui_img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cg_img];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(ui_img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Complete Code:

http://ihome.ust.hk/~tm_lksac/OpenGLSprite.m

The application usually calls `- (void)drawSelfIfNeeded:(BOOL)`needed
to update the texture in the application. But I want to take a "screenshoot" of the texture and save it as `UIImage` as further image processing.

Comment: Does your code work fine if you use the 4-byte RGBA instead of the 2-byte GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5? As described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4694198/19679), you will need to do a little conversion to bring in 5,6,5 format data into a Core Graphics bitmap context. Also, you're leaking a CGColorSpaceRef in the above code.

Comment: Brad, thanks for the link and it really helps. I can use the glReadPixels to get meaningful images. Now, working on details to get the right dimension and orientation.