# Axial symmetry on image

Tags: objective-c, ios

How could I apply an axial symmetry on an UIImage ?
I could not find anything whithin the apple documentation, etc..
I suppose i need to use quartz2d, but I've no more clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an image from its row data, by simply inverting the pixels using the method described here [Creating UIImage from raw RGBA data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545237/creating-uiimage-from-raw-rgba-data)