# iPhone : How in set alpha in UIImage on Touches with PIxel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, pixel, alpha

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


    NSSet *allTouches = [[event allTouches] retain];
    switch ([allTouches count])
    {
           case 1: {
           UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
           CGPoint touchPoint =  [touch locationInView:[self view]];
                if(touchPoint.x > rightleg.frame.origin.x && touchPoint.x < rightleg.frame.origin.x + rightleg.frame.size.width &&
                   touchPoint.y > rightleg.frame.origin.y && touchPoint.y < rightleg.frame.origin.y + rightleg.frame.size.height ){
                   rightleg.alpha = rightleg.alpha + 0.005;
                }
            }
        case 2 :{
            UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
            CGPoint touchPoint =  [touch locationInView:[self view]];
            if(touchPoint.x > leftleg.frame.origin.x && touchPoint.x < leftleg.frame.origin.x + leftleg.frame.size.width &&
               touchPoint.y > leftleg.frame.origin.y && touchPoint.y < leftleg.frame.origin.y + leftleg.frame.size.height ){
               leftleg.alpha = leftleg.alpha + 0.005;

            }
        }
    }


}
```

this code is set alpha on UIImage when user touches on Image, but How to set alpha on the pixel in UIImage when touches on that pixel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to convert your UIImage to a bytes array, make the changes and then save to an UIImage again.

Something like this might help:

- http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/
- [Can I edit the pixels of the UIImage's property CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281210/can-i-edit-the-pixels-of-the-uiimages-property-cgimage)