# UIImage remove some pixels issue

Tags: iphone, uiimage, quartz-2d, cgcontext, cgcontextref

I have the application where user can erase image.

So if user touches some px of the image, alfa of these pixels should become lower.

For instance, if I touched (0,0) pixel of the image one time, (0,0) px opacity should become 0.9. If I touched that px 10 times I shouldn't see image at point (0,0).

What is the best approach to implement that?

Comment: You must have very little fingers if you can precisely touch (0,0) pixel

Comment: You can use the Quartz core framework.
Refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit

Comment: one pixel is just for example

Answer (score 0):

This is the coe by which you can detect the touch values

```
CGPoint StartPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

CGPoint Endpoint = [touch locationInView:self];


NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",StartPoint.x];
NSString *strlx = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",StartPoint.y];
NSString *strcx = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",Endpoint.x];
NSString *strcy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",Endpoint.y];
```

here touch is the object for UITouch.

I cann't say anything about the opacity.

Comment: I don't need to get coordinates of touches, I need to change proper pixels

Answer (score 0):

If you want it fast (as in real time fast) you'll need to use OpenGL.
The best way to do it to create a mask of alpha values which will be applied on the original image using a custom built shader.

The easier way but slower is to get the raw pixels from the UIImage 
and applying the alpha values on the raw pixels array and then turning it back to a UIImage ([here is a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141485/413289))